# Garbage value problem , I want to get a garbage value but I am getting zero...Why is it so

Tags: c++, c++17

If we simply declare an integer variable in C++ , and print it why am I getting 0 instead of garbage value  every time. How to declare each element of array as 1 without using loop.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    cout<<a;    // displays zero
}
```

Comment: What garbage value do you expect? Why 0 is not a garbage value for you?

Comment: Why is `0` not a "garbage value"? `a` is uninitilised, there is no guarantee that it will be non-zero or that your program won't just crash

Comment: The value of an uninitialized variable is undefined. It is usually "garbage" (i.e. apparently random), but there is no guarantee. It depends on the compiler and more low-level details.

Comment: 1. Consider yourself (un)lucky? Them's the breaks of undefined behavior. 2. You don't (intrinsics notwithstanding).

Comment: If you don't give a (scalar) variable a value, then its value is not "garbage". It is _indeterminate_, which means exactly what the word says, nothing more. Reading an indeterminate value in itself causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you running a debug build?

Comment: The gcc gives warning ": warning: 'a' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]" that means undefined behavior and undefined behavior means that it may display "widehole" or 0 or format your hard drive. Be happy you got 0.

Comment: Reading an uninitialized scalar value is Undefined Behaviour.  Therefore you should have no expectations. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub